# How do I export a Sketch file with page names to PDF?

Tags: pdf, sketch-app

I have some files that I need to export to PDF. As a matter of fact, it's quite a repetitive task I have to do almost every day. So far so good, but the resulting PDF only exports pages with numbers as labels `(1, 2, 3....n)` and I need them to keep the page name. My user case is as follows: I create a screen, which may have several conditional steps and interactions based on different user flows.

At time of big deliveries, this is not an issue, because I use real user flow diagrams, so no big deal. But for quick exchange with my team members, I would need something fast. Right now, my only resource is to add a layer with the page name somewhere on the page. But this is quite confusing and unprofessional.

**Is there a way to export the pages with their respective names instead of numbers?**

Comment: If you really need names in your Sketch PDF files you could include the name on each design, maybe a placard on each "page"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a new official plugin from Sketch called Print Export Plugin. It lets you export artboards and pages on one page and also lets you export your user flows. It is amazing! I am sure this will help. Read more about it here -> https://blog.sketchapp.com/export-artboards-and-pages-for-print-with-this-official-plugin-from-sketch-e907f2ca29b4

Sketch Print Export Plugin: https://github.com/BohemianCoding/print-export-sketchplugin?source=post_page---------------------------

Answer (score 0):

No, so far we don't have any feature or plugin in sketch-app to export PDF with custom label as page number.

For PDF export in sketch-app, I use [PDF-export-sketch-plugin](https://github.com/DWilliames/PDF-export-sketch-plugin). Its very convenient to export as PDF based on artboard order. ["Custom label as page number feature" was requested](https://github.com/DWilliames/PDF-export-sketch-plugin/issues/21) in PDF-export-sketch-plugin's github page. Follow that issue in github to get latest updates.